# How to execute code written on the fly programmatically?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, module

I have an Access (2016, x64) project, where some forms are built programmatically from scratch by pressing a command button on a form, which we will call "ALFA".
Since I need to instantiate some class modules while using these new forms, I also make changes to their modules programmatically.

The problem is, I have to close and reopen the ALFA form "manually". If I close and reopen it "programmatically", the code won't run.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the code isn't compiled and saved.

Save this as a separate module:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
    
' Compile and save all (other) modules.
' Is intended to be called from the AutoExec macro after having verified the references.
'
' After tampering with the references, the application may appear to be compiled, which it is not.
' This function will not fail - even if the application is compiled or appears to be - if it is
' kept on it own in a separate module.
'
' It is not a subfunction as only functions can be called from the AutoExec macro.
'
' 2018-07-06. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CompileAndSave()

  ' The command:
  '
  '   Application.RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
  '
  ' can not be used, as no module is open when the AutoExec macro runs.
  ' Thus, use this undocumented SysCmd() call.
  Call SysCmd(504, 16483)

End Function
```

Then create a macro (yes) having one command only:

```
 RunCode (exact word is localised)
     Function name: CompileAndSave()
```

Now, when you have created you form's code, try to run the macro. Then, check if the code is compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I learned something new. But it doesn't work. If I enter a break statement (e.g. "Stop") after I close the forms by saving the changes made to their code modules, I get a message from the system telling me that it is impossible to stop execution at this stage. It's as if the execution process is still running despite closing the objects.

Comment: Done, but it doesn't work. I have tried to use VBScript to create another thread, but nothing. Only an user action works!

Comment: Then, I guess, you’ll have to rethink your concept.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The mistake I was making with VBScript was to invoke the Run method of the application instance to execute a procedure located inside the current project. If, instead, I run the same procedure with VBScript after rewriting it in a .vbs file, everything works. This way, the update of the .bas modules is done in a separate process. It is useless, as a self-taught user I lack the basics